# Python: grammar correct in a loop

Tags: python, loops, grammar

"I was doing the follow exercise:

*A gymnast can earn a score between 1 and 10 from each judge.*

*Print out a series of sentences, "A judge can give a gymnast _ points."
Don't worry if your first sentence reads "A judge can give a gymnast 1 points."
However, you get 1000 bonus internet points if you can use a for loop, and have correct grammar.*

My code is this:

```
scores = (tuple(range(1,11)))
 
for score in scores:
   print (f'A judge can give a gymnast {score} points.')
```

And my output of course was:

- A judge can give a gymnast 1 points.
- A judge can give a gymnast 2
  points.
- A judge can give a gymnast 3 points.
- A judge can give a
  gymnast 4 points.
- A judge can give a gymnast 5 points.
- A judge can
  give a gymnast 6 points.
- A judge can give a gymnast 7 points.
- A
  judge can give a gymnast 8 points.
- A judge can give a gymnast 9
  points.
- A judge can give a gymnast 10 points.

**The question is: How can I correct the grammar in my loop? I mean, when is "1 point" how can I make my loop to say "1 point" and not "1 points" and for the others scores maintain the "points"?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres another way of doing it. The answer above **may**(I don't know) be more efficient, in my opinion this is more readable for future developers.

```
scores = (tuple(range(1,11)))
 
for score in scores:
    if score == 1:
        print ('A judge can give a gymnast 1 point.')
    else:
        print (f'A judge can give a gymnast {score} points.')
```

Answer (score 10):

Conditionally add the `s` to the string:

```py
print(f'A judge can give a gymnast {score} point{"s" if score > 1 else ""}.')
```

Answer (score 5):

I conclude from the simplicity of this problem, that you are rather new to **Python** and **Programming** in general.

You should take a look at **fundamental-concepts** like **flow-control** and finding a solution shouldn't be hard at all.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

But still - to give you a concrete answer to the question,
you could simply add an **if-statement** to your **loop**
like this:

```
scores = (tuple(range(1,11)))
 
for score in scores: 
   output = f'A judge can give a gymnast {score} point'
   if score > 1: 
      output += "s"
   print(f"{output}.")
```

Answer (score 4):

All you'll need is an `if` statement to check the score

```
scores = (tuple(range(1,11)))
 
for score in scores:
   if (score == 1):
       print (f'A judge can give a gymnast {score} point.')
   else:
       print (f'A judge can give a gymnast {score} points.')
```

Answer (score 2):

A straight-forward way would be to use the python string format to conditionally render the `s`

```
print(f'A judge can give a gymnast {score} point{"s" if score > 1 else ""}.')
```